# php files are downloading instead of executing after installing SSL certificate

Tags: php, nginx

I was able to successfully access php files when I was only using **http** but now that I installed **https**, I cant access the page anymore instead I download the script.

This is my file at /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default

```
server{
root /media/world/web/dev;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost  web.dev;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Tutorials that I followed

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx  (Nginx - ubuntu 18.04)

The https is working, if I execute index.html it works fine.

Could anyone point to me on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default` file doesn't contain php configurations, or do you have another file in `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/` with it, as mentioned in the [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04) link? If not, it seems you might have accidentally removed the it while configuring SSL. Try adding the below before the Certbot configurations is the file:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
```

Comment: Man you saved me :) I was going crazy to why this wasnt working. certbot removed this bit of the code when I installed it. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @LukeDS all good buddy, am a SysAdmin :D

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! how is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not contain native PHP processing like some other web servers. So, before setup PHP configurations you'll need to install `php-fpm` package with the following command:

```
sudo apt install php-fpm
```

After then set up the rest of the configurations on your configuration file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```